# Is it possible to have multiple conditional ModelState validations on a single Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a large form that the user can save midway through but can't actually complete until all completion validations are satisfied. For example:

```cs
public class Employee 
{
  [RequiredAtCompletion]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [RequiredAtCompletion]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example, when a user tries to to save an employee form with no SSN populated, I want to fail validation under all circumstances. If they have SSN populated but no first/last name, they should still be allowed to save but shouldn't be able to "complete" the form until they've filled out first name, last name, and SSN.

Is there any way to do this with simple ModelState validation?

Comment: there's loads of answers on this, do a search for "custom validation".

Comment: There's definitely no shortage of custom validation solutions; however, I'm specifically looking for using ModelState/ValidationAttribute to perform multiple separate validations. Can you provide a link to one of the solutions you're referring to?

Comment: @BenjaminU.Going slightly off topic, I use fluent validation for all my validation, it's really flexible and can create lots of different combinations https://fluentvalidation.net/